# HTTP Status 400 - The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect. Spring / $.ajax()

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

This is my Controller:

```
package br.com.apptrechos.torcidapremiada.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties.User;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.core.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import br.com.apptrechos.torcidapremiada.model.Beneficio;
import br.com.apptrechos.torcidapremiada.model.Imovel;
import br.com.apptrechos.torcidapremiada.model.Partida;
import br.com.apptrechos.torcidapremiada.repository.Imoveis;
import br.com.apptrechos.torcidapremiada.repository.Partidas;
import br.com.apptrechos.torcidapremiada.service.BeneficioService;
import br.com.apptrechos.torcidapremiada.service.exception.DadoJaCadastradoException;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/beneficio")
public class BeneficioController {

@Autowired
private Partidas partidas;

@Autowired
private Imoveis imoveis;

@Autowired
private BeneficioService beneficioService;

@PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<?> validarBeneficio(@RequestBody Long codigo, @AuthenticationPrincipal User user) {
    try {
        Imovel imovel = this.imoveis.findByCodigoIn(codigo);
        Partida proximaPartida = this.partidas.buscarProximaPartida();

        Beneficio beneficio = new Beneficio(proximaPartida, user.getName(), imovel, imovel.getContribuinte());

        this.beneficioService.salvar(beneficio);
    } catch (DadoJaCadastradoException e) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(e.getMessage());
    }

    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}

}
```

My Javascript and my view:

```js
var TorcidaPremiada = TorcidaPremiada || {};

TorcidaPremiada.ImovelConcederBeneficio = (function() {
 
 function ImovelConcederBeneficio() {
  this.validaBeneficioBtn = $('.js-valida-beneficio-btn');
  this.containerMensagemErro = $('.js-container-mensagem-erro');
  this.containerMensagemSucesso = $('.js-container-mensagem-sucesso'); 
 }
 
 ImovelConcederBeneficio.prototype.iniciar = function() {
  this.validaBeneficioBtn.on('click', onBotaoValidaBeneficioClick.bind(this)); 
 }
 
 function onBotaoValidaBeneficioClick(event) {
  var botao = $(event.currentTarget);
  var codigo = botao.data('codigo');
  var url = botao.data('url');
  
  $.ajax({
   url: url,
   method: 'POST',
   data: JSON.stringify({codigo: codigo}),
   contentType: 'application/json',
   success: onSuccess.bind(this),
   error: onError.bind(this)
  });
 }
 
 function onSuccess() {
  var mensagem = 'Benefício concedido com sucesso!';
  this.containerMensagemSucesso.removeClass('hidden');
  this.containerMensagemSucesso.html('<span>' + mensagem + '</span>');
 }
 
 function onError(object) {
  console.log(error);
  var mensagem = object.responseText;
  this.containerMensagemErro.removeClass('hidden');
  this.containerMensagemErro.html('<i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i><span> ' + mensagem + '</span>');
 }
 
 return ImovelConcederBeneficio;
}());

$(function() {
 var imovelConcederBeneficio = new TorcidaPremiada.ImovelConcederBeneficio();
 imovelConcederBeneficio.iniciar();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
 xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
 xmlns:tp="http://www.apptrechos.com.br"
 xmlns:data="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/data"
 layout:decorate="~{layout/layout-padrao}">

 <head>
  <title>Torcida Premiada - Cadastro de Imóveis</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/stylesheets/vendors/bootstrap-switch.min.css}" />
 </head>

 <section layout:fragment="conteudo">
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="x_panel">
     <div class="x_title">
      <h2 th:if="${imovel.novo}">Cadastro de Imóveis</h2>
      <h2 th:unless="${imovel.novo}">Edição de Imóvel</h2>
      <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
                      <li>
                       <a th:href="@{/imovel}"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> <span>Pesquisa de Imóveis</span></a>
                        </li>
                     </ul>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
     </div> 
     <div class="x_content">
      <br />
      <form method="POST" class="form-horizontal form-label-left" th:object="${imovel}" th:action="@{/imovel/novo}">
       <tp:message />
       <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in hidden js-container-mensagem-erro" role="alert"></div>
       <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade in hidden js-container-mensagem-sucesso" role="alert"></div>
       
       <input type="hidden" th:field="*{codigo}" />
       <div class="form-group tp-required" tp:classforerror="inscricaoImobiliaria">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="inscricaoImobiliaria">Inscrição Imobiliária</label>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
         <input type="text" id="inscricaoImobiliaria" maxlength="16" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12 input-imobiliario" th:readonly="${not imovel.novo}" th:field="*{inscricaoImobiliaria}" />
        </div>
       </div>
       
       <div class="form-group tp-required" tp:classforerror="contribuinte.codigo">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="nomeContribuinte">Contribuinte</label>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
         <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" id="nomeContribuinte" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" th:field="*{contribuinte.nome}" 
           placeholder="Clique na lupa para pesquisar o contribuinte" /> 
          <input type="hidden" id="codigoContribuinte" th:field="*{contribuinte}" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default js-tooltip" title="Pesquisar" 
            data-toggle="modal" data-target="#pesquisaRapidaDeContribuintes" th:disabled="${not imovel.novo}">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
           </button>
          </span>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
       
       <div class="form-group tp-required" tp:classforerror="condicaoDeResidente">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="condicaoDeResidente">Condição de Residente</label>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
         <select id="condicaoDeResidente" class="select2_single form-control" tabindex="-1" th:field="*{condicaoDeResidente}">
          <option value="">Selecione uma condição</option>
          <option th:each="condicaoDeResidente : ${condicoesDeResidencia}" th:value="${condicaoDeResidente}" th:text="${condicaoDeResidente.descricao}"></option> 
         </select>
        </div>
       </div>
       
       <div class="form-group tp-required" tp:classforerror="situacao">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="situacao">Situação</label>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
         <select id="situacao" class="select2_single form-control" tabindex="-1" th:field="*{situacao}">
          <option value="">Selecione uma situação</option>
          <option th:each="situacao : ${situacoes}" th:value="${situacao}" th:text="${situacao.descricao}"></option> 
         </select>
        </div>
       </div>
       
       <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Status</label>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
         <input type="checkbox" class="js-status" data-size="small"
           data-on-color="primary" data-off-color="danger"
           data-on-text="Ativo" data-off-text="Inativo"
           data-inverse=true th:field="*{status}" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-6" th:unless="${imovel.novo}">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm js-valida-beneficio-btn" data:codigo="${imovel.codigo}" data:url="@{/beneficio}">Validar Benefício</button>
        </div>
       </div>
       
       <div class="ln_solid"></div>
       <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary js-cancelar-btn">Cancelar</button>
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Salvar</button>
        </div>
       </div>
      </form>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <th:block th:replace="pesquisa-rapida/pesquisa-rapida-de-contribuintes :: pesquisaRapidaDeContribuintes"></th:block>
 </section>
 <th:block layout:fragment="javascript-extra">
  <script th:src="@{/javascripts/vendors/handlebars.min.js}"></script>
  <script th:src="@{/javascripts/contribuinte.pesquisa-rapida.js}"></script>
  <script th:src="@{/javascripts/vendors/bootstrap-switch.min.js}"></script>
  <script th:src="@{/javascripts/imovel.condeder-beneficio.js}"></script>
  <script>
   $(".js-status").bootstrapSwitch();
  </script>
 </th:block>
</html>
```

When I click on the button, the ajax request doesn't reach to the controller. The browser console shows error `HTTP Status 400 - The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect`.

The followings are the request data.

[image: Header A]
[image: Header B]

Would anybody help me?

Comment: would you post the value of `var url` or request url?

Comment: URL is the path to the method. The CODIGO is the data I want it to be passed. I pull both the URL and the CODIGO through the .data () method.

Comment: `url` is the path to method. That would be the problem cause your controller method's path doesn't show a `url` value. You should have a check if the request url and your controller method's path have the same value.

Comment: Because the CODIGO's value is being passed in the request body. It's a POST request. Look at the image HEADER B the value being passed (codigo: 8).

Comment: Look where I get the value of the variable CODIGO and the variable URL.  [link](https://snag.gy/9SkGJ1.jpg)  I use the JQuery .data method to get them (look at the javascript code just above).

Comment: Could it be a :port issue?

Comment: I not believe it because I have others Ajax requests that are working.

Comment: Is the correct object logged? Should `console.log(error);` be `console.log(object);`?